# Minimize javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I am only new to javascript. I am using minify to minimize load time of CSS and JS files. I also compress the javascript in my HTML document (functions) using [jscompress](http://jscompress.com/) I am wondering if it was possible to even minimize the functions? I am running ajax updates so in my HTML document I don't want my linked PHP files listed.

Is there a way to minimize the function codes found in the HTML using minify or another alternative method to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can extract the javascript code found in your html pages into a separate file.

Wherever you are referencing php code like this `<?php echo var_name ?>` or something of that sort, send that as parameters into the appropriate "functions" in the new js file.

Now, process this newly created js file through the compression library.